# Unable to shrink partition size

Tags: windows, disk, partition

I am trying to install Linux in a computer that has Windows 7. The first step was shrinking the disk size but Windows did not allow any reduction. Thus I followed a number of steps to disable "unmovable" files

- I disabled the Page File
- I disabled hibernation
- I disabled System Protection

After that nothing seemed to have changed so I checked the disk fragmentation and it was 11% fragmented. I have since then run at least 4 defrags and I have also defragged the free space using [Defraggler](https://www.piriform.com/defraggler).

As of now the disk looks like this

[image: disk fragmentation]

Right now, Windows refuses to shrink the partition by any amount (I imagine that the files at the end of the disk are the troublesome ones).

Coming from an Linux background I am unsure what else needs to be done in order to shrink the partition.

Comment: Try gparted instead of windows to shrink. And I believe the problem is related to what windows considers unmoveable files at the end of the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The easiest way is just to use a Live USB with [GParted](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) on it since that will allow you to move Windows protected files around (the windows OS is not loaded on the live distro).

If just defragmenting is concerned one can use [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and the included Defraggler for the same purpose.

Comment: Must be a new version of parted/GParted. For instance the latest "redo" live-cd includes an older version that cannot resize NTFS file systems (yet?).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows disk management tool to do the shrink? Here's a link for that method.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows disk management tool, however it returns 0MB of "Size of available shrink space in MB" and does not allow me to type any number.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure the recycle bin on that drive is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 10. Turns out it was **antivirus software** that was running on the machine that **prevented defragmentation happen** properly. I actually had to temporarily uninstall antivirus. After that, the Disk Management tool was able to correctly shrink the volume.